# Get list of all checkboxes with checked and unchecked status

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have following code, to show an image along with its checkbox. It is either enabled or disabled

```
 if($ring["status"] != '1') 
                                        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="ringIds[]" value="'.$ring["id"].'">'
                                    . '<input type="image" onClick="openGalleryRing(\''.$ring['imagePath'].'\', \''.$ring['id'].'\');" src="http://thevowapp.com/iphoneapp/vowstore/rings/'.  $ring['imagePath'] .'" name="checked" value="' . $ring['id'].'" data-my-info="'. $ring['ringSetName'] .'" style="width:200px; height:200px; margin-left: 10px;"></td>';
                                    else                                         
                                         echo '<td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  name="ringIds[]" value="'.$ring["id"].'">'
                                    . '<input type="image" onClick="openGalleryRing(\''.$ring['imagePath'].'\', \''.$ring['id'].'\');" src="http://thevowapp.com/iphoneapp/vowstore/rings/'.  $ring['imagePath'] .'" name="checked" value="' . $ring['id'].'" data-my-info="'. $ring['ringSetName'] .'" style="width:200px; height:200px; margin-left: 10px;"></td>';
```

In my javascript i am using something like

```
$('.updateBtn').on('click', function()
        {
             var checked = $('input[name="ringIds[]"]:checked').serialize(); 
             if(checked !== '')
                 window.location.href = 'actions.php?j=24&' + checked;
             else
                 alert('No Rings are selected');
    });
```

This works, i can get all the checked checkboxes, but what i actually want is to get all hte list of checkboxes, which are checked and which are not. How can i modify this code?

Comment: if you get all the checked and unchecked elements how will you know which are checked

Comment: `var checked = $('input[name="ringIds[]"]').serialize();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. **Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.**](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Thus `.serialize()` will return only checked checkboxes whether or not you include the pseudo selector `:checked`.

You may want to use `.each()` or `.map()` to get the unselected checkboxes.

```
var unchecked = "";
$('input[name="ringIds[]"]').not(':checked').each(function() {
    unchecked += (unchecked.length ? '&' + '') + this.name + '=' + this.value;
});
```

Or:

```
var unchecked = $('input[name="ringIds[]"]').not(':checked').map(function(i,v) {
    return this.name + '=' + this.value;
})
.get().join('&');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which you are looking for:

```
$('.updateBtn').on('click', function()
{
    var check_boxes = $('input[name="ringIds[]"]').serialize(); 
    // Try below line to see all checkboxes
    console.log(check_boxes);

});
```

Comment: ringIds%5B%5D=12&ringIds%5B%5D=15&ringIds%5B%5D=19 this is what i get, clearly its showing only those which are checked. even with serialize

Comment: i want to get rings list which are checked and which are not checked